# How can I define my function when using REST API in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, json, rest, api, codeigniter

I created a controller named Api.php then I extended the Rest_Controller. I noticed that I can only use index_get() when creating a function in this controller

```
<?php

class Api extends REST_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index_get(){
        $car_id = $this->get('car_id');
        if(!$car_id){

            $this->response("No Car ID specified", 400);

            exit;
        }

        $result = $this->model_getvalues->getCars( $car_id );

        if($result){

            $this->response($result, 200); 

            exit;
        } 
        else{

             $this->response("Invalid Car ID", 404);

            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

but when I try creating my desired function like **getAllCars()** instead of **index_get()** I get an error message telling me unknown function.

How can I define my own function instead of using **index_get()** when using rest api library in CodeIgniter?

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#handling-requests, i think you missed this part: _the method names will be appended with the HTTP method used to access the request. If you're making an HTTP GET call to /books, for instance, it would call a Books#index_get() method_

Comment: I get what you're saying, the thing is can the index_ be dynamic such that I can name a method getCars_get(), getById_get() and so on and so forth

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i meant, but to be honest getCars_get is a bit redundant don't you think ? since you have the `_get` suffix already in there just name your method `cars_get()` and if you've a post request you can call your method `cars_post()` - but from outside its always the same namely `/cars/`

Comment: the thing is i'm new to using rest api in codeigniter, if i use cars_get() of which it's working, what if i want to fetch based on some conditions, how will i go about that @sintakonte

Comment: what do you mean with conditions ? something like  `/cars/?id=123` ?

Comment: i meant conditions like select * from car  where id = 83, select * from car  status = 1, and so on

Comment: Thanks i have been able to figure it out, i just found out that the name before the _get is what matters to the url i.e when one has a method like getCars_get, you will have to call it using just getCars without the _get attach to it, it work for me. it means that one can have more than _get method in the API controller.

Comment: thats exactly what i told you in my first comment ;)

Comment: oh thanks @sintakonte i really appreciate your time and moreover this is my first time working with or creating a restful api

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: okay @halfer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks i have been able to figure it out, i just found out that the name before the _get is what matters to the url i.e when one has a method like getCars_get, you will have to call it using just getCars without the _get attach to it, it work for me. it means that one can have more than _get method in the API controller.

Answer (score 0):

By default on https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver#handling-requests the method is index_get(),another way to use your own method is play with the HTTP GET parameter 
ex:

```
if($this->get('car_id') == 'all'){
  //your own function here
}
```

Or if you really want to create your own method you can refer on this http://programmerblog.net/create-restful-web-services-in-codeigniter/

Comment: define it in your route file.try like this
route['index_get']='api/index_get';

Comment: i don't get you @ferry sanjaya

Comment: did you read that article? if you want custom method like getAllCars() instead of index_get(),you must put suffix '_get' so getAllCars_get(),thats my opinion

Comment: i have tried that, but it's still throwing an error say unknown method

Comment: i tried it and works,do you test using postman and using GET request??.. show me your whole code which return error

Comment: Thanks i have been able to figure it out, i just found out that the name before the _get is what matters to the url i.e when one has a method like getCars_get, you will have to call it using just getCars without the _get attach to it, it work for me. it means that one can have more than _get method in the API controller.

Comment: @codedgift yeah,to call method on url you dont need put the suffix like _get(),_post(),etc and ya you can make more than one '_get()' method

Comment: yeah @FerrySanjaya, i never knew about that but now i know, thanks so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change function index_get() to getAllCars_get(),

`<?php

class Api extends REST_Controller{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

public function getAllCars_get(){
    
   //your code
    
}
```

}
?>
`
Like this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).